# python packages -- overriding built-in packages and the dreaded "Module xxxx was already imported" warning

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

I'm creating a self-contained python tool, located in a directory, which I want some colleagues of mine to be able to run with a standard python distribution that includes numpy and matplotlib. I don't want them to have to install additional libraries.

```
─myprogram
 |   __main__.py
 |   [...other .py files...]
 ├───datafiles
 ├───sandbox
 └───xlrd
     ├───doc
     └───examples
```

I am using the `xlrd` library, which I included in my program distribution so that they don't have to install it.

I've tested my program to make sure it works with Enthought EPD, PortablePython, and PythonXY.

Here's the problem: PythonXY can be installed with the xlrd library. When I went to run my program with PythonXY, I got this warning:

```
c:\app\python\pythonxy-2.7.5.0\lib\site-packages\scikits\__init__.py:1:
UserWarning: Module xlrd was already imported from myprogram\xlrd\__init__.pyc,
but c:\app\python\pythonxy-2.7.5.0\lib\site-packages is being added to sys.path
   __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

How can I tweak my source code so that it imports only the embedded xlrd library that I provide, and not the installed one, if one is installed?

---

Clarification:

1. Aside from the printed warning, is there any side effect that can happen? I want the embedded version of xlrd to be used, not the global copy installed within python.
2. If there's nothing wrong, how can I suppress this warning *for this library only?*

Comment: Have you tried inserting your module path in a higher precedence entry in `sys.path` than wherever the PythonXY's version of xlrd is?

Comment: Just tried printing out sys.path. The local directory is the first one in the list.

Comment: Do you import the package with `from myprogram.xlrd import...` ? (or `from .xlrd import...`)

Comment: oh, that's interesting, I didn't know you could do either of those. (I just do `import xlrd`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `myprogram\xlrd` to `myprogram\frozen_xlrd`.
Then import it with

```
try:
    import xlrd
except ImportError:
    import frozen_xlrd as xlrd
```

---

Alternatively, you could tell Python to silently ignore this particular `UserWarning`:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", 
                        message="Module xlrd was already imported", 
                        category=UserWarning)
```

Place this early on in the program, before `scikits` gets imported.

Comment: I'll fall back on that approach if I have to, is there anyway to force Python to import only from a local copy?

Comment: Sure, just `import frozen_xlrd as xlrd` (without the `try...except`).

Comment: no, I mean to use xlrd instead and specifically force python to use the package-local copy. The problem is one of namespace collision, and although I don't think `frozen_xlrd` is likely to give me a namespace collision with the installed Python libraries, I can't guarantee that someone else hasn't installed a `frozen_xlrd` library  that would leave me with the same issue.

Comment: Your local directory is the first one listed in `sys.path`, so your local `frozen_xlrd` will be the one that gets imported even if there is a namespace collision. And the `warnings.filterwarnings` call will suppress the warning.